# Space between elements - is this making the code cleaner?

Tags: html, css, usability, reusability, web-testing

This is example code, not an actual project I'm working on:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
div.infoguide {
width: 800px;
border: 2px;
height: auto;
}
div.mynews1 {
float: left;
padding: 5px;
background-color:yellow;
font-size: 14px;
width: 80px;
height: 600px;
}
div.mynews2 {
margin: 10px;
background-color: blue;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
width:400px;
height: 600px;
}
</style>
 <title>Mypage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="infoguide">
This is the header
<div class="mynews1">
It works!
</div>
<div class="mynews2">
Good it worked
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, is it better practise in website design to leave spaces between the elements to avoid confusion when there's multiple `<div> </div>` elements, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
div.infoguide {
width: 800px;
border: 2px;
height: auto;
}
div.mynews1 {
float: left;
padding: 5px;
background-color:yellow;
font-size: 14px;
width: 80px;
height: 600px;
}
div.mynews2 {
margin: 10px;
background-color: blue;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
width:400px;
height: 600px;
}
</style>
 <title>Mypage</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="infoguide">
This is the header

<div class="mynews1">
It works!
</div>

<div class="mynews2">
Good it worked
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My basic question; how should I go about making code cleaner and easier to understand, especially when designing website templates for my projects?

Comment: Adding Indentations, and using semantically meaning full elements like `section`, `header`, `nav`, `aside`, … instead of `div` elements, you cannot always avoid `div` element, but if you are about to use a `div` you should think about if it is only for styling purposes or if it has also a semantic meaning. And `<!-- comments -->` can also be useful.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is not suitable for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Also extract the stylesheets into a separate file to not have markup/structure and styling in the same file. Next to the already mentioned indentations, which IMHO are more important than using blank lines for visual separation.

Answer (score 0):

Clean HTML code generally has indentation so that it is easy to tell which `<div>` matches with each `</div>`.

You can automatically format documents with online tools or some text editors such as VS Code.

I think the space around each inner `div` helps but that is just a matter of opinion.

This is how I would format the HTML for readability:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        div.infoguide {
            width: 800px;
            border: 2px;
            height: auto;
        }

        div.mynews1 {
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
            background-color: yellow;
            font-size: 14px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 600px;
        }

        div.mynews2 {
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: blue;
            font-size: 20px;
            color: white;
            width: 400px;
            height: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Mypage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="infoguide">
        This is the header

        <div class="mynews1">
            It works!
        </div>

        <div class="mynews2">
            Good it worked
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```